# Extremely Long Job Times

Tags: google-bigquery

Since roughly 10:20EST this morning our application has been dealing with (dare I say it), ridiculously long job times-- outside the realm of what is normal.  It seems to only be happening in a particular dataset as well, as I've loaded and queried another dataset with the normal few second query time.  Anyway, some of these jobs still have a status of 'RUNNING' over an hour after their start time.  They are all load jobs as well, from google storage files.  One such job is job_dbbbf00a2a7440cfa7f5a9993ac736c5.  Does anyone have any insight into what could cause such a long wait?

Comment: The jobs in question just finished.  I guess this was just an intermittent problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not expected, it looks like we hit some timeouts. We're investigating, but it looks like things are back to normal now.